# Include header file in C curiosity

Tags: c, header

I have the following curiosity about the  include files and how they are managed (with `GCC`):

Let's say I have one source file **foo.c** and three headers **foo.h**, **foo_cfg.h** and **foo_int.h**.

In **foo.c**:

```
#include "foo.h"  
#include "foo_int.h"
```

In **foo.h**:

```
#include "foo_cfg.h"
```

In **foo_cfg.h**:

```
/* no inclusions */   
#define FOO BAR
```

In **foo_int.h**:

```
/* no inclusions */ 
#define BAR 0U
```

I am wondering why the compilation succeeds. Shouldn't the **foo_cfg.h** file complain that it doesn't know about BAR symbol?

Furthermore I have another source file **bar.c** which only includes the **foo.h** file and still works.

Remark: this is from a project I am working on with a complex build environment of which I don't have to much details. Could it be that the build environment has an effect on this other than specifying the location for the `header files`?

It might be that the question is really stupid or I've overlooked something and I apologize if so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's ok.

You see, the preprocessor doesn't care if BAR is defined or not at all. It just replaces the **string** FOO with BAR in the source code which follows, without actually caring if it's defined at that point or not.

Next, at the actual `.c` file (the thing where the compilation starts) both headers are included, so the compiler sees both substitutions: `FOO` -> `BAR` and `BAR` -> `0U`. So it successfully applies both of them.

The headers are never compiled alone, they are always compiled as a part of `.c` file which `#include`s that header. (The preprocessor just pretends that the content of the header is pasted to the place where `#include` is located.) So, for the preprocessor your file `foo.c` looks like this:

```
/* no inclusions */
#define FOO BAR
/* no inclusions */
#define BAR 0U
/* the rest of the file... */
/* for example: */
unsigned int i = FOO;
```

And the compiler after the preprocessing sees just this:

```
/* no inclusions */
/* no inclusions */
/* the rest of the file... */
/* for example: */
unsigned int i = 0U;
```

(not quite sure, maybe the preprocessor removes the comments as well.)

---

Edit:
Indeed, as @pmg mentions, the preprocessor replaces comments with a whitespace, so the real preprocessed text which is fed to the compiler is just

```
_
_
_
_
unsigned int i = 0U;
```

(here `_` denotes a whitespace)

Comment: You can do `gcc -E file.c` to output the file after all preprocessing has taken place, though this can get pretty long once you include any standard headers.

Comment: @Vlad: yes, the preprocessor removes comments in translation phase 3. See 5.1.1.2 in [the Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Comment: @pmg: thank you! The Standard quote is always an ultimate source of information. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

To extend Vlad's answer a bit:

Preprocessor macros are expanded when used, not when defined.
So when you write `#define FOO BAR`, all it does is remember that FOO=BAR.
When you write `#define BAR 0U`, it remembers that BAR=0U.

Now, when `FOO` is seen in the code, it's replaced with `BAR`, which is immediately replaced with `0U`.
The order in which `#define FOO` and `#define BAR` appear in the source is unimportant. The important thing is that when `FOO` is seen the first time, both definitions were already done.

Comment: Ahaaa! And that's why 'bar.c' doesn't complain about not having 'foo_int.h' included, because in fact it doesn't use any of the defines that depend on 'foo_int.h'. Well now I am enlightened!